# MySQL "Duplicate Foreign Key", but key doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I need to create a foreign key, but executing the following results in the  error: "Error Code: 1826. Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'FK_ProjectBase_Program'"

```
alter table ipos5.ProjectBase 
      add constraint FK_ProjectBase_Program foreign key (Program) references Program(OID);
```

If I execute:

```
select * 
from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'

result = def    ipos5   FK_ProjectBase_Program  ipos5   projectbase FOREIGN KEY
```

I can see the existing key definition, but if I show the structure for the target TABLE_NAME, it is not there.
This is on an active database with a large amount of data, using InnoDB, so dump/restore is a very last resort.
  I am using a 3rd party framework, which does not allow me to manually specify a foreign key name (so I HAVE to use the one specified), but my application errors during startup because it cannot create the key.
  Is there a way to rebuild the information_schema database? I am really hoping to avoid doing a dump and rebuild of the application database, as it is quite large.

Comment: please, add the sql that you are using, and the db scheme, if very difficult to see what is wrong, just with your question.

Comment: did you check if already data exists in the table

Answer (score 0):

I ended up duplicating the table structure, copying the data into it, dropping the original table, then re-creating it and copying the data back. Orphaned foreign key reference is now gone.